# Why does file generated by Sping Boot application have different encoding when app runs locally (in IntelliJ) and once deployed on Ubuntu server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding

How can I ensure that the deployed application running on Ubuntu generates a file that has the same encoding as my file created when my app runs locally in IntelliJ ?

I've set the pom.xml to have the below

`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>         <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>`

but I'm still seeing the same issue.  Any ideas on how to ensure the files generated locally and on deployed app are identical ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does you code generate a file? If yes, how does it generate it? Since the properties you've provided are for **source code** of you application, not files generated by your application.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Yes I create the file using Files.write(path, list, StandardCharsets.UTF-8) which creates files with UTF-8 encoded which I've confirmed.  The discrepancy I'm seeing is that the file generated on Ubuntu server has the UNIX(LF) versus the Windows(CRLF).  How can I ensure that my server side app creates a file with the Windows(CRLF) instead of UNIX(LF)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Line ending differences are completely unrelated to character set encoding.

You can either use `System.lineSeparator()`, which will write the appropriate line separator ***for the platform the process runs on***, or pick one (LF or CRLF), always use that, and write your code based on that.

Note that `readLine()` works with either:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF).

If you are *writing* the file using `println()` then you'll get the default line separator for the platform the code runs on. You'll get `\n` on Linux, and `\r\n` on Windows.  If you need to force one line ending regardless of the platform, then you must use `print()` instead and write your own line endings.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  When you said "or pick one (LF or CRLF)" what do you mean there?  In my code I use \r\n for all new lines but the file created has the UNIX line endings...

Comment: I have edited my answer.